# java application converting to junit testing

Tags: java, junit

I have this java program:

```
public class countOccurances {

    public void countOccurancesInString(String str){

        char[] c = str.toCharArray();//in order to convert the string into a char array that will help us handle the string easily
        int loopCount=0;
        int count=0;//this variable will count every occurance of every character

        int len=str.length();
        if(len>1000){
            System.out.println("String size is bigger than 1000 characters which is illegal, program will terminate..." );
            System.exit(0);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){

            boolean flag =true;

            for(int k=0;k<i;k++){
                if(c[i]==(str.charAt(k)))
                    flag=false;
            }

            if(flag){ //after we notice that we have several occurences of the character we want to count it 
                for(int j=0;j<len;j++){
                    if(c[i]==str.charAt(j))
                        count++;

                }
                System.out.print("'" + c[i] + "'" + ":" + (count) + ",");
                count=0;
                loopCount=0;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

And I want to convert it to junit testing which will provide me the option to test several unit test cases that will tell me if different values will pass or fail the program and I am struggling doing it.
any ideas?

Comment: Could you describe what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Graham- of course I want to be able to test my program with several parameters in order to test my program with several optional cases in the program. for example if number of characters in the string is bigger than 1000 the test will fail.

Comment: But what is the code supposed to do?

Comment: The code is counting number of characters occurances in a string , for example if you got the following string "abbbba" it will return a:2,b:4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, first things first: Java class names should usually start with a capital letter, and method names with lower case.  With that out of the way:

Outputting to `System.out` isn't a very clean way to wite a method.  This is referred to as a **side effect** - that is, you call the method, it does "something" and returns.   It's also arguably a violation of the **Single Responsibility Principle**.  It's doing two things: working out your answer *and* deciding how to display it.  This limits the method's usefulness to your one application (spitting it out to the console) but not alternatives (e.g. outputting it to a web page, filtering it for a specific character, or - and this is where we come in - *testing it*).

It *is* possible to test this code, by redirecting `System.out` and using a mocking framework such as [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/):

```
@Test
public void testCountOccurrences() {
  PrintStream mockSystemOut = Mockito.mock(PrintStream.class);
  System.setOut(mockSystemOut);
  new CountOccurrences().countOccurences("AABBCCD");
  Mockito.verify(mockSystemOut).print("'A':2,");
  Mockito.verify(mockSystemOut).print("'B':2,");
  Mockito.verify(mockSystemOut).print("'C':1,");
}
```

But you're starting from shaky ground: get your method signature right first.  What you probably want is a `Map<Character, Integer>` - that is, a set of pairs of characters with their counts.  That gives the caller much more flexibility about how it uses the information:

```
public Map<Character, Integer> countOccurrences(String str) { ... }
```

Then, at the point you call the code, you can choose to output that information to the console if you wish (in fact, most `Map` implementations have a built-in `toString()` method which will probably give you what you want - it's not precisely the same output, but may work for what you want to achieve).

For your implementation, create a `HashMap<Character, Integer>`:

```
Map<Character, Integer> result = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
```

Add your pairs to it rather than outputting to the console:

```
result.put(c[i], count);
```

And return the result at the end.  Then your test looks like this:

```
@Test
public void testCountOccurrences() {
  Map<Character, Integer> expected = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
  expected.put("A", 2);
  expected.put("B", 2);
  expected.put("C", 1);
  assertEquals(
    expected,
    new CountOccurrences().countOccurences("AABBCCD");
  );
}
```

One final thought: adhere to the principles of *Test Driven Development* - write your tests *before* you code it!

Comment: By the way, if you follow my advice, you can re-write you code to be considerably shorter, simpler and faster.  You don't need a char array.  You only need one loop.  Just pass through the string once, and use the `Map` you are building as a set of counters which you increment each time you encounter a character.

Comment: Ok I fixed my program, now if I wnt to use the default libraries of java how can i do that?

Comment: how can i contact you @Graham?

Comment: public void countOccur(String str){

 int len = str.length();
        HashMap<Character, Integer> charCountMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>(Math.max(len, 1000));
 
        char[] strArray = str.toCharArray();
 
    
 
        for (char c : strArray)
        {
            if(charCountMap.containsKey(c))
            {
                
 
                charCountMap.put(c, charCountMap.get(c)+1);
            }
            else
            {
 
                charCountMap.put(c, 1);
            }
        }

    }

Comment: I suggest you use an IDE such as Eclipse or IntelliJ.  They will make a lot of this stuff a lot easier.

Comment: How can I build the string again from the hashMap like:
expected.put('C', 2);
  expected.put('B', 2);
  expected.put('^',3);
  expected.put('A', 5);
and I want the string to be 'CCBB^^^AAAAA'?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't really the place for this sort of conversation. You have a new question, so raise it separately and someone can help you out.  Good luck.